# Pandas: writing a function which returns bin interval midpoint together with mean of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've written the following function:

```py
def binning(df, end, numberofbins):
    df = df[df['xaxis'] <= end]
    bins = np.linspace(df['xaxis'].min(), df['xaxis'].max(), numberofbins)
    groups = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['xaxis'], bins))
    return groups.mean()['yaxis']
```

I'm now trying to extend this function so that instead of returning the intervals in the x-axis, it instead overwrites this with the midpoint of the bin intervals.

I'm not sure how to tackle this as while it is stated that while the bin intervals are saved in an index, I'm not sure how to index to only the numbers in the intervals and perform any operation onto them and proceed with replacing it with those midpoints.

EDITED TO ADD: I've tried beforehand, to add `retbin=True` at the end of `pd.cut()`, but got an error. My guess is this is due to the `df.groupby` function not being able to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** This adjusts your function so that it returns a series of means whose index is the midpoint of the intervals instead of the intervals:

```
def binning(df, end, numberofbins):
    df = df[df['xaxis'] <= end]
    bins = np.linspace(df['xaxis'].min(), df['xaxis'].max(), numberofbins)
    labels = np.diff(bins)/2 + bins[:-1]
    groups = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['xaxis'], bins))
    return pd.Series(groups.mean()['yaxis'].values, index=labels)
```

If you're just looking for the midpoints of the bins, you are only using the dataframe for subsetting with 'end' and for getting the lower and upper bounds of the bins. If that's the case, this should work:

```
def binning_mid(df, end, numberofbins):
    df = df[df['xaxis'] <= end]
    bins = np.linspace(df['xaxis'].min(), df['xaxis'].max(), numberofbins)
    intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(bins[:-1], bins[1:])
    midpoints = np.diff(bins)/2 + bins[:-1]
    return pd.Series(midpoints, index=intervals)
```

Comment: I was hoping that the function returns a series with both the interval midpoints AND the average of the grouped y-axis elements, hence my original return.